# Google sheets query can't compare for example Jan2020 with Dec2019

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm working on google sheets to compare sales + purchases data. My query formula works until I select January 01 of any year, it then has to compare it to Dec 01 of the previous year. It seems my query cant compare the previous month if its in the previous year.

**my query:**

```
=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(EOMONTH(SUPPLIER_INV!D:D,-2))}, " SELECT * WHERE (month(Col1) = " & month(B2)-2 & " and year(Col1) = " & year(B2) & ") ",1)
```

I use dropdown list that gives me dates in B2.

Answer (score 0):

month in QUERY starts from 0 eg. 1 = February not January. try:

```
=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(EOMONTH(SUPPLIER_INV!D:D, -2))}, 
 "where month(Col1)+1 = "&month(B2)-2&" 
    and year(Col1) = "&year(B2), 1)
```